# Same RSA key pair for all users

Tags: ssh, rsa, key-generation

Let's say in my computer running Debian i have an RSA key pair generated by user `foo` and copied the public key to `server_A` for allowing key based authentication in `ssh` for `foo`.

Now my question is can i use the same key-pair for user `bar` and `loo` to allow key based authentication for them on `server_A` or do i need to create a separate key pair for each user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about security, you can do that.

Otherwise, you absolutely need a different key pair for each user. If multiple users share the same private key, they can easily impersonate each other. If you're only doing key authentication (no passwords) then they can log into each other's accounts.

Comment: but if the OP is ok with that, can it be possible?

Comment: It's possible to do that, but it defeats the purpose of key authentication.

Comment: @JustinLardinois: If i want to do so then copying the public key to the server for all users and private key to all users home should do, right?

Comment: I guessed the OP was ok with that ..... :)

Comment: if you do that, foo can ssh into bar's account by doing ssh bar@server_A. You might as well create a single user and ask foo, bar and loo to use the same user account.